# Set range using variables inside loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of different names in column AA, same names in column AB but different order, and some random numbers attached in colums AC and AD. What I'm attempting to do: if name in AA equals name in vertical, check if name in AB equals horisontal. IF so, use intersection of the ranges to find the cell and (as an example) multiply the random numbers from AC and AD. Do this for the entire namelist. Namelist can vary in length.

I get a error when trying to set vertical as a specific range, but I'm not sure what to set the range to outside for, when I want to use variables in the range inside for.
Do share if you have other tips aswell, this probably won't be my last error or problem with this code.

```
Sub match()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim namelist As Long
Dim vertical As Range
Dim horisontal As Range
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim z As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
'Set vertical = ?
'Set horisontal = ?
nameList = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 23).End(xlUp).Row
verticalLength = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
horisontalLength = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For x = 2 To namelist
    hname = Cells(x, 27)
    vname = Cells(x, 28)
    For y = 2 To verticalLength
        vertical = Range(Cells(y, 2), Cells(y, 21)) '<---- Error 'object variable   or with block variable not set'
        If vname = Cells(y, 1) Then
            For z = 2 To horisontalLength
                horisontal = Range(Cells(2, z), Cells(21, z))
                If hname = Cells(2, z) Then
                isect = Application.Intersect(Range("vname"), (Range("hname")))
                isect.Select
                'rest of code
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Desired result:

[image]

Comment: Try `Dim iSect As Range` (currently you did not declare this variable, which is sloppy coding) and then use the `Set` keyword when assigning to this, because it is an object variable and that's how you have to do it.

Comment: Use `Set vertical = Range(..)` , `Set horisontal = Range(..)` and `Set isect = Application.Intersect(..)`

Comment: thanks guys. I gotta read myself up on this abit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub match()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim namelist As Range, vert As Range, hor As Range
Dim rw As Range
Dim hCell As Range, vCell As Range, fCell As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        Set vert = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        Set hor = .Range(.Range("B1"), .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
        Set namelist = .Range(.Cells(2, 27), _
                              .Cells(Rows.Count, 27).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 4)
    End With

    For Each rw In namelist.Rows

        Set hCell = hor.Find(rw.Cells(1).Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        Set vCell = vert.Find(rw.Cells(2).Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)

        If Not hCell Is Nothing And Not vCell Is Nothing Then

            Set fCell = ws.Cells(vCell.Row, hCell.Column)
            fCell.Value = rw.Cells(3) * rw.Cells(4)

        End If

    Next rw

End Sub
```

Comment: works like a charm. I'll study the crap out of this one. Thanks alot